# Nuxt: Passing props to use as parameters in fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

im making a ecommerce and in the product detail page i call a component, that must catch the first category of the current product and then find 4 product that match the category, im making the call like this:

/products/_slug.vue

```
          <div v-for="(category, index) in product.Categories" :key="category.name">
                 <div v-if="index === 0">
                   <RelatedProducts :categoryName="product.Categories"></RelatedProducts>
                 </div>
           </div>
```

i try to pass the props to relatedProducts.vue and try to use it in the fetch, but the script cant reach the categoryName:

```
export default {
    name: 'RelatedProducts',
    props: {
        categoryName: String,
    },
    data(): { products: Product[] } {
        return { products: [] };
    },
    async mounted() {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/product/find/page/1/${categoryName}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.products = data.response;
        console.log(data)
    },

}
```

what can i do? the get method is working in the api and im using Typescript if it could help.

Comment: Are you using nuxt3 or nuxt2 ?

Comment: Nuxt 2.7 or something like that

Comment: Anyway its bellow 3